# Why does LogCat not show the full message?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

Anyone knows why Logcat doesn't show full message?
I try to print xml response from my site but I only can get some of it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your logcat has reached its max size, see [What is the size limit for Logcat and how to change its capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat) 
Try using this code to write your result into a text file in sdcard, then use [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)  to get it.

```
 public static void appendLog(String text)
{
    File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.txt");
    if (!logFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

put your cursor on the error ,you will see the full log-cat info.