# Not able to complete message in logcat

Tags: android, json, android-logcat

I am getting a response from server in json format and it have more then 5000 lines. 
My problem is that I am not able to see complete json value in logcat and I already increase buffer size from eclipse logcat. I can not use this url in PC's web browser to check the json value because it's using some tokens to identify device. I have only one solution that I have to write a file with this json value and than extract it to my PC.

Anyone know some good solutions please help me.

Comment: try to make log.txt file programatically through code in sd card and extract it from DDMS. -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772657/why-does-logcat-not-show-the-full-message

Comment: I already done it. Can I make a file which will directly saved to PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your lengthy response and print it like this:

```
int maxLogSize = 1000;
for(int i = 0; i <= veryLongString.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
  int start = i * maxLogSize;
  int end = (i+1) * maxLogSize;
  end = end > veryLongString.length() ? veryLongString.length() : end;
  Log.v(TAG, veryLongString.substring(start, end));
}
```

Comment: thanks @amalBit, but I want to know a way which can resolve my issue in standard way provided by eclipse/android.

Comment: do you that how i can write this log into a file which will be saved in my PC.I already know how to write a file which will saved in mobile device but there are more effort to export this file into PC. If you know please give me solution.

Comment: There is no default way to do this. Its the limit given by the logcat.. You can only have work arounds.. This is a much simpler way than to save to a file and retrieve it.

Comment: but its also take more effort to format my json structure. If I use above solution than in each message I have some extra values and I have to delete these extra text from message and create required message and then format my JSON value.