# Creating Image Data Url using android.util.Base64.encodeToString from Byte Array

Tags: android, base64, data-url

I have been trying to produce image data URL from a byte array using the following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

/* Fill byteArrayOutStream with data */

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String encodedData = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutStream.toByteArray(),
                                           Base64.NO_WRAP);

stringBuilder.append("data:image/jpeg;base64,");
stringBuilder.append(encodedData);

// Log the result
android.util.Log.d("Base64Test", stringBuilder.toString());
```

`byteArrayOutStream` contains the correct data, as I have tested saving it as a jpg file and view it on device.

I test the data URL output by piping logcat's result to a file, copying the whole line, and paste it into Chrome.

What I see in chrome is totally blank. If I check it in the Chrome inspector, a blank JPG with the correct size is there.

I tried downloading it as a jpg file and open it with Windows Photo Viewer. It seems to be corrupted:

[image: Corrupted Image Sample]

The only visible part of the image on the left top corner is the correct data though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is caused by the buffer size of logcat being limited.

The `stringBuilder` indeed holds the correct data, however when printed in the log it is truncated by the limited buffer size. Simply add a `for` loop and everything will get printed.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat) for more info about logcat's buffer size.