# Not getting complete data from Json

Tags: android, json

Here I am trying to get Json data from URL. But oit is displaying only partial data. Below are the details how I am reading the data

BufferedInputStream is;

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
HttpResponse httpResponse = getHttpClient().execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = new BufferedInputStream(httpEntity.getContent()) ;

public void getJsonwithByteArray(BufferedInputStream istream) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int ctr;
    try {
        ctr = istream.read();
        while (ctr != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
            ctr = istream.read();
        }
        istream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v("Text Data", byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
    try {

        // Parse the data into jsonobject to get original data in form of
        // json.
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(
                byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
        jObj = jObject;

        Log.v("JsonParser", "JsonByteArry data: " + jObj.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your response in Json ? Post your Json Response also.

Comment: I guess the log has a limit. Check by parsing the json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat. check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this method to Read Response**

```
public String getResponseBody(final HttpEntity entity) throws IOException, ParseException {


        if (entity == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity may not be null");
        }

        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

        if (instream == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (entity.getContentLength() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(

            "HTTP entity too large to be buffered in memory");
        }


        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, HTTP.UTF_8));

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

        } finally {
            instream.close();
            reader.close();
        }

        return buffer.toString();

    }
```

**How to use?**

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
HttpResponse httpResponse = getHttpClient().execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String response = getResponseBody(httpEntity);
try {

        // Parse the data into jsonobject to get original data in form of
        // json.
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(
                response);
        jObj = jObject;

        Log.v("JsonParser", "JsonByteArry data: " + jObj.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response, especially Biraj for detail explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try out below method:

> ```
>  /*
>  * Call the Webservice read the Json response and return the response in
>  * string.
>  */
> public static String parseJSON(String p_url) {
>     JSONObject jsonObject = null;
>     String json = null;
>     try {
>         // Create a new HTTP Client
>         DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
>         // Setup the get request
>         HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(p_url);
>         System.out.println("Request URL--->" + p_url);
>         // Execute the request in the client
>         HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
>         // Grab the response
>         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>                 httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
>         json = reader.readLine();
>         System.err.println("JSON Response--->" + json);
>         // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
>         jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
> ```

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // In your production code handle any errors and catch the
        // individual exceptions
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

Use above method to parse the json response as below:

> ```
>    String abcd = CommonUtils.parseJSON(url);
> JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(abcd);
> ```