# Only get half of json date when call api

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

My response code is 200 and i get the data succeed , but i find that my json data is not complete .I really don't know why , is my code has something wrong ?

Here is my get data function:

```
private String getRouteJson(String url) throws IOException {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();    
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");    
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");    
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            Log.d(TAG, "responseCode:"+responseCode );
            StringBuilder jsonIn = new StringBuilder();
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonIn.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "responseCode:"+responseCode );
            }
            connection.disconnect();
            Log.d(TAG, "jsonIn:" + jsonIn.toString());

            return jsonIn.toString();
        }
```

I get the data that stuck when go to `,"EDUFDATE":"2017/09/07","SPONSER":"Asian EUS Group","EDUTYPE":"Dom`

This is my get api:
http://114.35.246.42:2212/MobileApp/DEST_WebService.asmx/GetEduData

I havn't meet the issue before , i really don't know hot to fix it.

Is any one can help me solve this problem ? That's would be appreciated !

It gets data util "Dom  and stop...
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you get any error. Please Update your question with Logcat So that we can understand

Comment: This might be happen due to heap size.

Comment: I update the logcat , take a look please.

Comment: How do you know you are getting only part of the output? If you are logging huge data, logcat will not display it completely. But the complete data is present jsonIn.

Comment: What do you mean about heap size , how do i fix it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607632/not-getting-complete-data-from-json check this out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat-and-how-to-change-its-capacity

Comment: Logcat will not display it completely , is that true ? I really don't know the information , i try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to view full Response ??

Check Following way.

1. Add Breakpoint where you get response.
   [image]
2. In DebugConsole there is one option view Check Image
   [image]

It will show your full reponse

Comment: Thank you very much , it really a huge help for me . I know how to handle my issue now .

Comment: @徐博俊 Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You are logging huge data in logcat. Logcat will not display it completely. But the complete data is present jsonIn string. You can continue working on the output

As @shayan commented, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat-and-how-to-change-its-capacity) if you want logcat to show complete data

Comment: Thanks for your responding , but it more complicated than using break point. Thanks your help again.