# AndroidHTTPResponse returns clipped content

Tags: android, httprequest, android-networking, androidhttpclient, bytearrayoutputstream

I am using the following piece of code to perform an HTTP Request in Android. Everything seems fine, but it appears that the response gets clipped at some point and I can't read the full content of the requested url.

Is there any size limit on the response?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(someUrl);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    out.close();
    String responseString = out.toString();
    Log.w("Response", responseString);  // The response is clipped at some point
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, silly me. Turns out this is a log problem. I checked out for size and the full content is there. The problem lies with the size limitation for LogCat, as explained in the following answer.

[What is the size limit for Logcat and how to change its capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat)

Cheers