# Can't get full body of HttpResponse

Tags: java, android, google-directions-api

I put my code in AsyncTask, in OnPostExecution, the result in Dialog is different from the one which is logged in Logcat.
The one in Logcat is incomplete, the one in Dialog is complete

Here is my code:

```
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{     
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        String url =params[0];
        String data = "";
        try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
            int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(status == 200){ //Receive OK
                data = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("HTTP", "ERROR");
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);    
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(result);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.create().show();
            Log.d("Response", result);
    }
```

In method onCreate(), I executed DownloadTask:

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=10.9052136,106.6928473&destination=10.736465,106.710779&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
downloadTask.execute(url);
```

I want to receive complete result to parse to JSON

Comment: Works fine for me. Where are you logging `data`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: you got full of string?
I got a "..." at end of String

Comment: may logcat truncates your string if too long?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

and see [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/823393) if you **really** need it as a `String`.

Maintaining it as an `InputStream` and passing **that** to the JSON parser would be better though.

Comment: I used Scanner to pass InputStream, the result is the same

Comment: I editted my code
Could you answer my question again?

Comment: @TrươngVănTrọng Why? You've been given a solution. Why should this poster help you with a different one? What's wrong with the one he provided?