# Java system.out not printing all occurances

Tags: java, android, xml

I am currently parsing an XML document and storing the XML data in a String[]. This is what I do:

```
db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse(in);
Element docElem = dom.getDocumentElement();
NodeList valuesList= docElem.getElementsByTagName("values");

Element value = (Element) valuesList.item(0);

//Split on every white space
String[] myValues = value.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().split("\\s+");

System.out.println(myValues.length);
//Output: 5400 

for(String val : myValues){
    System.out.println("Value: " + val);
    //This prints out random amount of lines in the console, see figure.
}
```

The output from the loop varies. See the picture below.

[image: sysout]

The result could be 4145 the first execution and 4198 the second time.

Shouldn't this output be 5400 lines since the String[] holds 5400 items? Why is it not?

Thankful for any kind of explanation.

Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out` goes to logcat and the logcat is just a buffer with limited capacity. When the capacity is exceeded, older entries are thrown out. The proportion of your `System.out` messages in the buffer depends on other logcat activity in the system.

See [What is the size limit for Logcat and how to change its capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat)

Answer (score 0):

If Logcat size limit is not your problem then try the following as well -

```
    //Split on every white space
    String[] myValues = value.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().split("\\s+");

    System.out.println(myValues.length);
    //Output: 5400 

    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(myValues);

    List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(stringList);

    synchronized(list) 
    {
       Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); 

       while (iterator.hasNext())
          System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```