# String Buffer is unable to convert whole data in String using toString

Tags: android

Error:

> String Buffer is unable to convert whole data in String using toString

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = "";
StringBuffer  buffer =new StringBuffer();
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line +"\n");
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "line:" + line);
}
/* Close Stream */
if (null != inputStream) {
    inputStream.close();
}
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "buffer.toString():" + buffer.toString());
```

Comment: in the above code it returns only stating few 200 -300 characters converted into String

Comment: The log only shows a number of characters. You won't find the whole file in there.

Comment: The log buffer is limited, see here how to change it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat-and-how-to-change-its-capacity And try to log `buffer.toString().length()` to get the real size of your string.

Comment: it was ok actually Log can display limited content in AS ,thanks #Neria Nachum