# Static String variable containing base 64 encoded bitmap cut in the middle in android

Tags: android, string, string-concatenation, string.format, messageformat

I have a static string variable which I use to send data to the server from another class.

The message I want to send contains 5 string fields (one of them is a base64 encoded bitmap string) seperated by the character "|".

My problem is that the string just cut in the middle. The only parts I see are the first field and the base64 encoded bitmap (probably not even all of it).

I tried creating the string with MessageFormat, String.format and a regular string concatenation but none seemed to work.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Here is my current code:

```
   toSend = "UPL|" + photo +"|" + Double.toString(location.latitude) + "|" +
                    Double.toString(location.longitude) + "|" + mapName;
```

The logcat prints this:

> UPL|iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPwAAAC9CAIAAAAYzYf5AAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4
>                                                                        nGy97a4kWXIcaGZ+IvPeqq7uGQ6JoSgQAveHnnCx+7ILCCssJGqGmuEM++tmhpvtDz+RVdTuBRqo
>                                                                        rrr5FeHH3dzM3JP/8PsbHUlIGEf1lG6N+FxLH2dX1W3d209JtgEIfPRZVYWgcWDxtrqfB2XgdEsy
>                                                                        YZ+sdZgAHukVQkWmuyUBejgSFkgSgKSH+whJ0kkCGoAMiNJayAdT0Ud6qZLYvtcCkDQcKB+sm6q7
>                                                                        b0Ao20u0Lek8z6qDDskz57woySQAjCbJKESIBdmGOL8gsOOlMgLAtkCI9ll1pM0SyYQAkpBJe0mQ
>                                                                        bDOZj4XrhyTskPNsJEOvKme/nwrm7XT3ojokecIHC7TtQHMvgiZZKANH1bMbYndLMCItOGJIPt2L
>                                                                        UgAkEtodqpAEkQqJOxYLyaISnugKzAQssR2SIeB0p6rgdKxVdAM5k7WWz54busAk0X7pAgE8432d
>                                                                        OiwBgPMADruLdGBKq+1a+3rChJLEEIDuJ0lJv6IVfOJKYjSAn+KSnJKU9gE9+rEEE4gmouq33y2R
>                                                                        BIqq41BQFAEuOb1WHVo8+4RJPs+zJIIlnPCdxxMm0bCCtlso6ulnlQAFeKaXcMeyKKDdAIo6pCKI
>                                                                        JBC4mO528Lbk05KSRABJViLHHzkTVjGBYMSLNUFZZMcAAeZsJGC6TcYJUYZLKwkBEySuOCSAeazE
>                                                                        KgE5QAdV5Xhi1Am0b4AEQSFISmVbJEEFiUEIiH0cR9tJJIH7sQkBAuk4QYg4VWWEFDyflwBC2EEI
>                                                                        hCVSHZeEzF+szIlFBAHEfDSbUhAyAAgGWSKixEXZZqltkgJFnT7XWu0GSYp4ZYF0cJPMeSF0e96Y
>                                                                        wCRSJakCESQlkYSE3p/6qFuYD59JbqQBEz/3UwEBgZwr6Ri5rdsjKYAswQRdaDtiUw+4+zwoMme7
>                                                                        SqAdLKockR/pJ1Jaady4HmcfEu3AJiwAOpUG2KjvP93vvCU40Wd3rWp3YnEZiVvkSQg8qAJDlIg2
>                                                                        S3PnQ9A5JBMQjYSsyEnIVcWQ8MEyAuZYlaDBdqS6sQg0TPIm7vyKicUsFoClBYIqAEGAzKWWCPAZ
>                                                                        0FxQz+mVAARcayUmy7FUIEQ94YlWSu0GC4wkaQEQ4cZiQex4ToX2E7aootwGwOsMYN5TEoC1mMwh
>                                                                        9DeHKklVSZpAJ3CrZQJAqRISUCkITBFOisI+AiJ0zlElRc7ZmUObZFXZxg5zzmkEIs7hhsgY1JxY
>                                                                        KVhVTxgADBC2AQlCGMxtZIAFNDIJCBApgLHnU69S4jlmAES2g6CqCFRV9+lE+yThJECwdAuLAmln
>                                                                        Hkjy0X2rslOUICNJlg6GJqDcWJ0cOgR2cqg6ecL3dTNCUKgPhmCVEi5Wukt1Mod02ksHzhzrVp++
>                                                                        WyQfsREUnXzR8SiciRCJHvjBQojFs5sqqRI/VTfU0y4WqQJuqoQKWesDNvAWqvQTejLTgtqBaKe4
>                                                                        2qfAVWwCAVhzD0KW9PC5VABUTGJkCUiEiiQKgaQiO2mAVIkBGBUpCiFFXSUd3EeCmCBRgDkBJNMx
>                                                                        SClgApAJEk+YEiDlubzcoSCJAcmqMgiAQuxjLYeYiOEOaIJhpHLmVEKSA4JzbpBILHKi3dgxlF0O
>                                                                        40SS4xcgNDKHs1TzkHm3ADNxv+ET5veTgDxjQlJJRaF0TETvEwzMiQ0CMp7npx2Sx6q217oNOtvF
>                                                                        i4wqgBNNZbAVTJorLUhtC/PSAyVlWNScUUGBb1UIPTlpCpwEYJnP7nuVVOd53tZ6OlQdYMITeMYN
>                                                                        lpaJR/ed5QRVEtoOOPDlWIc69eVzfRB3Vamqys6ZKPxkfQiHiuQZT5LDebJEoN0Sb10IIi7Uk86i
>                                                                        DZ0+iY7XWmgHFFFTlJOmQD5sSQhXKTDrOHujNoAGDiroQ2uSGbmrDKH2KXHy1PwTgCqdadWKM/cb
>                                                                        TPbpcgajZFIhPeXbTWpC4UIeGcSbRBRBMdFgwQkAggMG80q0ojZ0AbA/bhoBNRFwlQFwIioRK/Pa
>                                                                        BKkApQIiYO0Qxy4ghBOQENxYqwjNG5kWawCepOuXKfH6pIjpoFZNfWiDqgSTuJEgcIdkd4eWdp8j
>                                                                        sqryqrlA24I06ZlMmtQGlBP7mY/D0koQcFIDsS/4XDsFJZ2AxMTal4RGzNgWRMpJoMRPd4FJjloI
>                                                                        HkLHT7dKgNvdzBR8DOgKkjZJ6dknABDxKQgGgRNn/e67e2md8ZLSLbDCIC0QdlLSZLYjzCGHlkwi
>                                                                        uZM/0YSMPojuLpaT21IBp32vFQAxgNu6Pb0BQwhKi6RTxef5nIAieaimsk/SHawk8WmDLEoaBIEL
>                                                                        dUCCg5LiBiIN9IBKSdZaG2ZckMPoQoGUJBJtXilwstu+RWD3KQlUjEWKdbWhALBUO7hIoq7bD1YB
>                                                                        Sfy2lhOCh6ZwUyhQAJCeWOE09z5vtfsTX3AoCQhAVdMCcvCkNnpJiYQw7xwgYBpRaTIFKBbLgTSf
>                                                                        HdOELNXuqgntKhCSg7bPzAeUbXGDouyXFmzVIKLsGzQnlNfzD/RPSBR42hCdiEoyWAjAgjpdUhsh
>                                                                        ipp2fulwfCJLiljgsZQYVBO2SwcYVrnP2+3mxAjDgDex3beqKj27b6uYoKASwEZavtWq9+9gm6G7
>                                                                        dRRfOBVQbUjqBLGZMy5FgZkb9AHLfNOtBjsvdeeo+tUd8FCd9sTBIBBMkEVATNkxd6+2agFXSwCk
>                                                                        JvqSKfwNEFXVcbHckQYKspGJxSvv8opLkpxWkldyvoBNPdLzeMzNsGvVzq6aNheclEoGLpaopDOV
>                                                                        AYO5J0gCyAkkbkyVAGsKupZCgCFX6XRLBVhSd1eV07bTDtTTvw7FwAm9QfZoe0mJKQIhp9Yx6GwM
>                                                                        4JDTt8zpI4Zpid2cGoLrozGDJuGQFLDEEDad+c25mIN3RAq0VO0+qmwE3oeWXBQhqmITqZpThwRF
>                                                                        HLUaEUiW4WYWtbg6FkIUyHrlr6nTFCXYocm03QirTj+L5bRVZU8RbWGpHNykZ3wMfJXWVSTbZ1Ex
>                                                                        qpbB7rO+fK6VrKpQnT5CE+2sqqQZIWyfVAAeNadizgHeUAWcscVDenSLC0ERDlvzUSmyAShHrcED
>                                                                        omxPL1JFEZ2sKiR9npLO7onUOXWHJLJtRQChZaKD4KxdkDcvKV3UxPWH3UrOMd6NIYVdtQl4Pr7t
>                                                                        eJK4uH8jThJVxei40bXkHV00DFDQFAcxQBwM8h52B9cLhRsfJQjpDJsFYlC1AGru9+Ty4WFiXXhm
>                                                                        QAmYr1wqUqyggTAaEG/3LoaTTpLSMQ/eZOjO+oy7SovV3ReG4/Cn2lVoLlp1TOL0iRD0NFPcrU4R
>                                                                        ebZFrlVObCROzCrHA95sJyBYkPsM0olqnW5d9fUYpEcxOc+uquGU3B2g0wyeck4f5OIwsrhpffRT
>                                                                        UehFns5uxJO2qbg9uLSSSpzU7777VBBZU5sGHd3rdhJvt/WIFdxVn7SyljyIoAJEsrNqrapfH4+Q
>                                                                        RRk4VGYOEmIcJtPOE2SQaKC7yJMRtUpEYhgplaRDlYTiDsfkNuU9c4bLCZA7NxImEFqY98aEHAIw
>                                                                        r/jxYKF9AruL0ld6hIOLKBRrkjdRg1oYDXzQzrsXVNI+lZpPOnDFKZGiHSfTXJ7dIKumknDkDW36
>                                                                        pTBXfEhCgFAQIQssjUSBTH0aMpFcUncPDzqAYRoDTMRwwttVhYhD56sSa/pLaVohouaYq8rBmYAw
>                                                                        9/0CYIeq7IwxHwcLJGBsDLM5ZYJSt+e6DK09HfpWIRJWlbQ/JlksANIhYlWBjKenSpAUp8UqkuSt
>                                                                        1hNc0oKOVbtGrXrEEJZxAhR6E6rsIYVBBFXrbE9OmhRSv/1889wq4hf3QRJ8+nmvPM+nyNtAMSpt
>                                                                        ayAHQRzFwQtnBiPmKAhx8lY604CW1MT0Fbzy1QRTJhkhdO+cDgACwoA03IfWGSNNcDgHCGmvqhGP
>                                                                        do/VXVq4+i2AzjlEsomFIqeMyu62VYWpfZfM1GmVnOnxMbV5ULJeeTEpK

note that the start of the base64 is after the "UPL|" in the start of the string

Comment: Logcat buffer limitation. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat-and-how-to-change-its-capacity

Comment: I don't think so. Increased the maximum to 16M per log buffer but still showing only part of the string. Also, didn't get the full string in the server side

Comment: @GiliJacobi have you checked if you are within the limits of a String size? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179996/6142219

Comment: @Deepakkaku already checked- my string length is 80335

Comment: can you try just sending the base64 string?

Comment: `Increased the maximum to 16M per log buffer `. Does not matter. Every statement is limited. Your string is too long. Only a part is printed. Use string.length to check.

Comment: OK thank you for your help